# Is it okay if I connect my nikon dslr d3200 to my computer via usb connector while taking pictures?

Tags: nikon-d3200

I took a pictures with my camera while connecting it to the pc and the pictures I took suddenly appears to my camera's sd card folder, Im using Nikon D3200, Is it okay if i use it while connecting or it will damage the camera or the Sd card?

Comment: technically no damage.

Comment: @editinit [Short answers as comments — please resist the urge](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/q/4655/11924)

Answer (score 2):

Photos will be stored on the sd card in your camera no matter what its hooked up too. And it wont do any damage but if you trying to take pictures and interact with your sd card (e.g. transferring, deleteing, editing file) at the same time you might throw some errors and not be able to accomplish what you were trying to do. A good example is if you were transferring all your photos from your sd card to another drive while taking a picture. If you did this you might lose the photo you took, or stop the transferring process. All that being said i would say that an instance where you needed to do this is rare indeed. So dont worry your not going to hurt your camera

Comment: Even if I'll immediately transfer the photo that I'll take to another folder on my computer if it appears on the sd card folder on my pc, so i could upload the picture as soon as possible?

Comment: You should be fine. As long as the file isn't still saving on the sd card your fine. If you take multiple pictures at one time your camera lag a little and you'll want to wait on it to "catch up" before you move any files